# PHP Returning False Before Being Ran

Tags: php

In my PHP program, I have 2 radio buttons and a submit button. Button 1 = echoing out EST Button 2 = echoing PST. That works fine. The thing is, my false value is already being echoed out before I choose a choice. How can I get the script to run after I click the submit button? (Code below);

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['EST'])){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
    $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
    echo $today;
}else if(isset($_POST['PST'])){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
    echo $today;
}else{
    echo 'Please select a choice!';
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    Select your time zone: <br/>

    EST: <input type="radio" name="EST"/>
    PST: <input type="radio" name="PST"/>
    <br/></br>

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit!" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm! Thank you so much! Too bad I can't vote up comments yet :(

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here, you can either wrap the entire PHP block in a `isset($_POST['submit'])` conditional (can be substituted with @jeroen's conditional) **or** you can submit your form to a separate script for processing.

**Method 1**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // The submit button (and entire form) has been posted, continue:

    if(isset($_POST['EST'])){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
        $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
        echo $today;
    }else if(isset($_POST['PST'])){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
        $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
        echo $today;
    }else{
        echo 'Please select a choice!';
    }
}

// Form goes here
```

**Method 2**

*form.html*

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    Select your time zone: <br/>

    EST: <input type="radio" name="EST"/>
    PST: <input type="radio" name="PST"/>
    <br/></br>

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit!" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

*submit.php*

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['EST'])){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
    $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
    echo $today;
}else if(isset($_POST['PST'])){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
    echo $today;
}else{
    echo 'Please select a choice!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to run the first part of your code if a POST request is made. So you should wrap it in:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // your php code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(isset($_POST['EST'])){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
        $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
        echo $today;
    }else if(isset($_POST['PST'])){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
        $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
        echo $today;
    }else{
        echo 'Please select a choice!';
    }
} else {
?>

FORM

<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: [`$_POST` is always set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), however you can do `count($_POST)` to see if any data has been posted.

Comment: If form is not submitted $_POST is not isset

Comment: All the superglobals [seem defined to me](http://ideone.com/dSkp1S) (except for `$_SESSION` which required a session to be started).

Comment: Just tested this. I can confirm $_POST is always set even when no form is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['time_zone'])){
    if ($_POST['time_zone'] == "EST")
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
        $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
        echo $today;
    } else if($_POST['time_zone'] == "PST") {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
        $today = date("F, l jS Y g:i:s a");
        echo $today;
    } else 
        echo 'Please select a choice!';
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    Select your time zone: <br/>

    EST: <input type="radio" name="time_zone" value="EST"/>
    PST: <input type="radio" name="time_zone" value="PST"/>
    <br/></br>

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit!" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, but this would get your desired result without having to change much.

```
}else if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo 'Please select a choice!';
}
```